# what is this underscore.js "safe reference" code doing?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm learning Backbone, which uses Underscore.

In some examples, I see initialization code to create an empty array of children like this:

```
// inside a constructor function for a view object that will be extended:
this.children = _([]);
```

The Underscore function `_` above being called is defined near top of Underscore.js:

```
// Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.
var _ = function(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
    if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
    this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

Stepping through in the debugger shows me the `return new _(obj)` is called at first, so the function is called again and finally `this._wrapped = obj` is executed.  `this` appears to be referring to `_`.

I am bewildered.  Why not just say `this.children = []` in the first place?

Comment: Thomas, where'd you see `this.children = _([]);` snippet? I'm interested in something similar

Comment: In thoughtbot's PDF book.  https://learn.thoughtbot.com/products/1-backbone-js-on-rails

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `this.children` needs to be a instance of underscore: a specialized class that wraps an array, not just a regular javascript array literal. The code in the `_` function just makes sure it's always one `_` instance wrapping one regular array, even if you try to rewrap an underscore instance repeatedly, call _ with or without the `new` keyword.

```
//new _ instance wrapping an array. Straightforward.
var _withNew = new _([]);

//automatically calls `new` for you and returns that, resulting in same as above
var _withoutNew = _([]);

//just gives you _withoutNew back since it's already a proper _ instance
var _doubleWrapped = _(_withoutNew);
```

Comment: I understand your explanation of **what** is happening, but I'm still a little unclear as to **why**.  The Underscore.js library defines the function `_` which then has a lot of properties (mostly functions) defined on it.  Why would I want my array to be an instance of Underscore? Does this allow me to use the underscore array and collection functions as methods of my array, rather than passing my array the way the documentation suggests, e.g. `_.first(array, [n])`.  And even if this is true, what about functions like `_.isNaN(object)`.  How does this benefit my array?

Comment: Yes, it's so you can turn an array into a supped-up underscore array and then use the underscore functions on it later. I don't think it's common to do that, though, but I believe that is the intention of the outermost `_` function itself.

Answer (score 1):

From http://underscorejs.org/#chaining

You can use Underscore in either an object-oriented or a functional style, depending on your preference. The following two lines of code are identical ways to double a list of numbers.

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(n){ return n * 2; }); // Functional style
_([1, 2, 3]).map(function(n){ return n * 2; }); // OO style
```

So when using the OO style, the _ is used as a constructor function. Without the first two lines in the constructor function that "Creates a safe reference to the Underscore object" you would have to use the `new` keyword, as follows

```
new _([1, 2, 3]).map(function(n){ return n * 2; });
```

Now you don't :)